# Generate file by WebService through URL with query params (.NET)

Tags: asp.net, .net, generate

I've a customer that needs access a WebService through the URL, but he wants the URL the following way:

> www.website.com/saf-t/generate.zip?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-01-31&simple_version=1&tax_number=203413421&purchases=0&accounting=0

Not `generate.zip/p1=a1&p2=a2` but `generate.zip?p1=a1&p2=a2`. Is this possible to achieve?

I'm using `.NET 3.5`

I've tried the following way: create an `default.aspx` in a folder called `generate.zip`, but it assumes that it's a file and doesn't recognise the parameters without the `/` bar

Comment: May be this can be the right candidate for Url Rewriting feature in asp.net.

Comment: The issue is the `.zip` extension, the app interprets it like it is a zip file, and I can't use `generate.aspx`

Comment: Use Begin_Request event to capture your request and then use the Url rewriting feature to redirect the request to a known page within your application.